# Does the change in kinetic energy of an object depend on the reference frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames, energy-conservation

If we consider two inertial reference frames $S$ and $S’$ where one moves with respect to the other at a velocity $v$. If we find that in the reference frame S we have that the change in the kinetic energy of a projectile of mass m is $\Delta K_S=\cfrac{1}{2}m\left(V_2^2-V_1^2\right)$. And using the other reference system it is obtained as $\Delta K_{S'}=\cfrac{1}{2}m\left(V_{2*}^2-V_{1*}^2\right)$. Is it possible for equality $\Delta K_S = \Delta K_{S'}$  to be fulfilled?

That is, I wonder if it is possible that $\cfrac{1}{2}m\left(V_2^2-V_1^2\right)=\cfrac{1}{2}m\left(V_{2*}^2-V_{1*}^2\right)$?

Comment: Change in kinetic energy is reference frame dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. In the case of one-dimensional motion with $0 \leq |v|$ the changes in kinetic energy of a particle traveling at speeds $V_1$ and $V_2$ w.r.t. the reference frame $S$ w.r.t. which the reference frame $S*$ travels at velocity $v$. The changes are $\Delta K_S = \frac{1}{2}m(V_2^2 - V_1^2)$ and $\Delta K_{S'} = \frac{1}{2} m ((V_2 - v)^2 - (V_1 - v)^2)$ with $\Delta K_S = \Delta K_{S'}$ if and only if $V_1 = V_2$ or $v = 0$, that is the trivial case. In the multi-dimensional case, we can similarly obtain the analogous necessary and sufficient condition for equality in the change of kinetic energy calculated using the two different frames as $(\vec{V}_1 - \vec{V}_2)\cdot\vec{v} = 0$. In the non-trivial case, this condition essentially means that the differential $(\vec{V}_1 - \vec{V}_2) \perp \vec{v}$, that is, the differential occurs in a direction perpendicular to $\vec{v}$, thus leading to the interpretation related to the one-dimensional analog.

Notice that the application of the work-energy theorem (work done by external conservative forces on a material particle $W$ equals the change in it's kinetic energy, in the absence of non-conservative forces) would also need to incorporate the change in reference frame of observation. Let us take a brief look at the case in which $S$ is an inertial reference frame, so that $S'$ is one as well because we assume that the latter moves with respect to the former with a constant velocity $\vec{v}$. Abusing the notation, the work done (in the context of the analysis above) calculated using the two reference frames is then obtained as $W_S = \int_1^2 \vec{F}^\text{ext} \cdot \vec{V} \; dt$ and $W_{S'} = \int_1^2 \vec{F}^\text{ext} \cdot (\vec{V} - \vec{v}) \;  dt$. Verifying the statement of the work-energy theorem by evaluating these integrals is a good way to understand that $W_S = \Delta K_S$ is in general not equal to $W_{S'} = \Delta K_{S'}$, with the condition for equality being $(\vec{V}_1 - \vec{V}_2) \perp \vec{v}$.

In the case that either one or both reference frames are non-inertial, application of the work-energy theorem is more complicated than the analysis presented here.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually the total "energy-momentum" which is frame independent. Kinetic energy change is not frame independent. It is indeed frame dependant. The kinetic energy depends on momentum, where in units with $c=1$, the total energy is given by $$E^2=p^2+m^2$$ where the kinetic energy is represented by $p^2$.

Note that momentum is a vector and transformations that include rotations will mean the momentum components in one frame will differ in another.

But if the kinetic energy is conserved in one frame where *momentum is also conserved*, then the kinetic energy will be conserved in another frame.